# Commons-DBCP equivalents of Alfresco's db.pool.idle and db.pool.min?

Tags: alfresco, connection-pool

[Alfresco](http://alfresco.com) uses [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp) internally, and exposes DBCP parameters via its own parameter names.

For instance, `db.pool.initial` in Alfresco actually refers to `initialSize` in DBCP.

Most parameter equivalences can be guessed by comparing the [Alfresco doc](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Database_Configuration) and the [DBCP doc](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html), but I am unsure for two of them:

What are the DBCP equivalents of `db.pool.idle` and `db.pool.min`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.pool.idle` corresponds to `maxIdle`

`db.pool.min` matches `minIdle`

You can look them up in `./alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/core-services-context.xml`

The same applies for various other parameters.